# How to call a non-const operator?

Tags: c++, constants

So I'm having trouble trying to call a specific operator. In some class, I'm given:

```
template <class Object>
const Object& MyVector<Object>::operator[] (int index ) const {
    if (index < 0 || index >= mSize)
        throw MyException();
    return mObjects[index];
}
```

and I'm also given

```
template <class Object>
Object& MyVector<Object>::operator[]( int index ){
    if (index < 0 || index >= mSize)
        throw MyException();
    return mObjects[index];
}
```

I want to call the second one so I can modify the value, but the compiler keeps telling me that I can't do so because I'm trying to modify a constant.

Here's where I'm trying to use the operator function:

```
template <class Object>
const Object& Matrix<Object>::get(int r, int c) const{
    MyObject *row = & MyVectorObject[r]; //error
    //snipped
}
```

And I keep getting the error: cannot convert from `const MyObject *` to `MyObject *`

Comment: how is `MyVectorObject` declared?

Comment: Is your `MyVectorObject` const ?

Comment: You weren't given permission to modify those objects, so don't do it.

Comment: I'm almost tempted to give him an answer involving `const_cast` but I'm not sure if I want to be that evil today.

Comment: Always post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How are we supposed to solve this without knowing what `MyVectorObject` is??

Comment: I declared MyVectorObject in my constructor using MyVectorObject = new MyVector[someSize]

Comment: Ah, if `MyVectorObject` is a class member then the problem is that you are trying to modify it inside a `const` member function.

Comment: thanks @sjdowling, that was exactly it. i didnt post the method i was calling it from because i didnt think it was causing the problem

Comment: And what do you do in overloaded operator?

Comment: How is your `Matrix<>` object defined? It is a `const`? **ADD:** Oh it doesn't matter because the function is `const` so it won't allow you to change any member variables. **ADD:** Try `const MyObject *row = & MyVectorObject[r];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Matrix<Object>::get()` method is const, so if you access class attributes of Matrix in that method, all of them will be considered as const.

`MyObject *row = & MyVectorObject[r]` will effectively calls `const Object& MyVector<Object>::operator[] (int index ) const`.

`const Object& MyVector<Object>::operator[] (int index ) const` will return a `const Object&`.

So `MyVectorObject[r]` is of type `const Object&` and `& MyVectorObject[r]` will be of type `const Object *`

You should write:
`const MyObject *row = & MyVectorObject[r];`

Answer (score 2):

To call a non-const member function (including an operator) of an object, the object/reference must be non-const. If the function is called through a pointer, it must be a pointer to non-const.

In your case `MyVectorObject` is const and therefore the const overload was called. It's not apparent from your code, *why* it is const, but in the comments you reveal that it is a member. Members are implicitly accessed through `this` pointer and inside const member functions `this` is of course a pointer to const.